# Entity framework with dynamic table creating

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I worked on WPF project and connection to MySQL database.
My application is a host and can connect to multi equipment (Equipment1, Equipment2). After connecting to Equipment, all message between host (my app) and equipment need to store to database. Because data for logging is very large, I need to create logs_eqp_[eqmID] table for each equipment (example: logs_eqp_001 for equipment 1, log_eqp_002 for equipment 2).

So, could I use entity framework for this architecture? How could I do?

Regards,

Comment: Yes you can. How could you? You can find many tutorials.

Comment: The answer to "very large" is probably using `long ID` instead of `int ID` values, so you don't run out of ID values before the universe comes to an end.

Comment: @ Muhammad Saqlain: could you give me helpful document. I tried to find but could not

Answer (score 2):

I do not see why would you want to create tables dynamically. It would be much easier to have a single table with an indexed column for equipment name, so you could group, sort or filter your logs by equipment; with this approach you could avoid creating tables in runtime and can just use Entity Framework by the book by manipulating a single collection.

Comment: I am working on business project with a lot of data push to an equipment and I have over 1000 equipment in my system. All data to push to a table for all equipment is not good. That why I need to separate data to multi table.

Comment: "All data to push to a table for all equipment is not good" - are there any special reasons for that?